# fragment communication between two fragments in different activities

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

### I am trying to learn fragment communication in android, I have learnt interfragment communication between two fragments in a single activity using the [**example from developers site here**](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html)

---

I want to know how to communicatate between fragments in two different activities, ive posted a snapshot below

[image]

---

- Can someone show a sample program
- are there any standard developers examples out there, if true please
  point me to that source  any other online docs, blogs that explain
  this concept crisply

***note***:: i am aware of knowledge of communicating between two activities using intents when fragments are not involved

Comment: is there any other fragments in both the activities?

Comment: @Tamilselvan .... No .... it is exactly same as i explained in diagram

Comment: then what is the need of fragments here?

Comment: @Tamilselvan ..... Actually i am learning here so i have formulated a simple use case .....in future i will add multiple fragments ...

Comment: your current scenerio is wrong, you have fragment 1 and if u want to open the fragment 2 means u have to pass the intent to the activity 2 and from that activity only you have to start the fragment right. so if want to pass the data from the fragment 1 to fragment 2 means you have to send data from fragment 1 to activity 2 ans pass again the data to activity 2 to fragment 2. that s y i asked there is no need of fragments here.

Answer (score 0):

A fragment class inside an activity is usually public static. That's why its possible to launch the fragment from another activity.

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

you have fragment 1 and if u want to open the fragment 2 means

- u have to pass the intent to the activity 2 and from that activity only you have to start the fragment right.
- so if want to pass the data from the fragment 1 to fragment 2 means you have to send data from fragment 1 to activity 2 ans pass again the data to activity 2 to fragment 2 while creating the fragment 2 from activity 2